# Is XMLHttpRequest responseType="document" supported in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-level2

Information on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/xhr2) says that Chrome supports XMLHttpRequest Level 2.
I used [example from MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest) in my Chrome extension:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  alert(this.responseXML.title);
}
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.responseType = "document";
xhr.send();
```

However, `xhr.response` and `xhr.responseXML` are both `null` in `onload` (status is `200 OK`).
Is this supported in Chrome and where people actually look to find out whether it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDC documentation says it's supported in Chrome 18+. What version are you using?